# Nginx multipart upload - upstream server temporarily disabled while reading response header from upstream error

Tags: nginx

I am sending a multipart file upload from Android device to my API. Here is my nginx location/ server script/ and errorlog. Please help to sort out. How to handle this multipart upload.

```
 location ^~ /upload/pic/ {
            
            limit_req zone=PERIP; #zone=PERIP:10m rate=1r/s
            proxy_redirect          off;                
            proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Connection "";    
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            
            
            client_max_body_size 80M;
            client_body_buffer_size 80M;
            client_body_timeout 120;
            proxy_pass   http://backend;  
            proxy_buffering on;
            proxy_buffer_size 1k;
            proxy_buffers 24 4k;
            proxy_busy_buffers_size 8k;
            proxy_max_temp_file_size 2048m;
            proxy_temp_file_write_size 32k;
            proxy_request_buffering off;
        }
```

Python Server script :

```
async def upload_pic(self, request):
        async for field in (await request.multipart()):
            if (field.name == 'imagefile') and (is_allowed_imagefile(field.filename)):
                filename = field.filename              
                size = 0   
                with NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w+b', suffix='.jpg') as imagefile:
                    while True:
                        chunk = await field.read_chunk()
                        if not chunk:
                            break
                        size += len(chunk)
                        imagefile.write(chunk)
                    imagefile.flush()
                    imagefile.seek(0)
                    imagefile.read()
```

......

Nginx error  log for 2 upstream servers:

```
*10 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: xxx.xxx, server: example.com, request: "POST /upload/pic HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/mapp_1.sock:/upload/pic", host: "example.com"
*10 upstream server temporarily disabled while reading response header from upstream, client: xxx.xxx, server: example.com, request: "POST /upload/pic HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/tmp/mapp_1.sock:/upload/pic", host: "example.com"
```

Comment: Your app crashed. That's not something we can help with, but you can get Python debugging help on our sister site [so].

Comment: @MichaelHampton, this was working with my development server. My doubt is, If I use proxy_buffering in nginx side. Do I recieve it at app's end as a single file or multipart ??

Comment: It doesn't matter if it worked before. You still need to look at the traceback and figure out what the error is.